# Commerce Number Pattern

Tags: commerce

My system environment:

1. OS - Windows 10 64-bit
2. Local Server Stack - WampServer
3. Drupal 8.9.8
4. Theme Droopler
5. Module Commerce - installed using Composer and enabled by Drush

The Status Report (screen capture as below):
[image: status report]

The setting for Commerce Number Pattern:
[image: default pattern]

Despite clearing the cache after updating the default number setting, Drupal still reports an error as shown above.

Any assistance is greatly valued.

Thank you.

Comment: I think I had that too, goto `/update.php` and run the update.

Comment: I did that many times but to no avail.

Comment: I conjecture that the module (commerce_number_pattern) is used by commerce cart. I have googled and find no resources directly applicable to the issue. Commerce 2.x also is not very helpful for a newbie like me. Still trying to decipher the issue and come up with a solution. I even tried to create a yaml (yml) file. The status remains the same. Will try another attempt after a cool-down. Thanks for those reading and keeping the discussions alive:-)

Comment: `drush entity-updates` is the solution according to [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2601762). If you don't have Drush run [#24 code](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2601762#comment-10835098) once by placing it in a preprocess or a hook temporarily.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it and update the result:-)

Comment: No luck. I think the issue is still about how to configure the module commerce_number_pattern. Anyway, I appreciate your effort@NoSssweat

Comment: It's not about configuration at all. Drupal is detecting that you have commerce_number_pattern installed, but the entity type definition that ships with that module has not been created. It usually means that module installation failed for some reason, and now you need some Drush magic to resolve it (if update.php didn't work).

Comment: @BojanZivanovic. update.php didn't work. That's what I am looking for. Until now, I cannot find the answer. Any tip will be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please install Devel module.
[Link to Devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel)

2. enable devel module.
3. click on reinstall module.
   [image]
4. check module "Commerce Number Pattern".
   [image]
5. click on reinstall.

Hope this helps you.